# How can ı make space key work as it should for intellij on mac?

Tags: macos, intellij-idea, space, keymapping, blank-line

I am trying to use Intellij for java.I am on a mac.
Space button doesn't work as it should.
In order to leave a blank,ı must use shift + space.
Tried keymap and various other things,nothing worked.
What am ı doing wrong?

Tried keymap,remap some options etc.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Maybe you could contact the IntelliJ support team via IDE main menu `Help | Contact Support` for helps. Pressing space should be able to enter the space in IntelliJ otherwise it might be an issue in IntelliJ. Also, try disabling all downloaded plugins and use the default Keymap to see if it helps.

Answer (score 1):

After two days of trial and error,ı found the answer myself:
Settings/Accessibility/Keyboard
There you should untick "Full Keyboard Access"

I have never encountered such a problem before thus ı might have not expressed myself correctly.